# SSIS package failing from stored procedure when running as other than the creator

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have at least one (that I know of) issue with running a deployed SSIS package from a stored procedure. The procedure runs correctly from Visual Studio, as well as when I run the stored procedure as the person who created the package (who is also a sysadmin). But when I run it as anybody else, it fails without throwing any errors that I can see... though the following error appears in the event log:

```
Application: ISServerExec.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Configuration.SessionConfiguration.!SessionConfiguration()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Configuration.SessionConfiguration.Dispose(Boolean)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Configuration.SessionConfiguration.Finalize()
```

The package in question is an ETL package which imports an Excel .xlsx file to SQL Server 2019 Standard.

In the project settings in Visual Studio, Run64BitRuntime = False. Also, ProtectionLevel = DontSaveSensitive (for the package).

The stored procedure which runs the project is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [impexp].[udp_ImportSpreadsheet_PersonActionsAndEvents]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ActionID int
    , @FileName nvarchar(250)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @execution_id bigint

    DELETE FROM [impexp].[PersonActionsAndEventsImport_CellNoMatch]
    WHERE ActionID = @ActionID;

    EXEC [SSISDB].catalog.create_execution
        @package_name=N'EventsImport.dtsx',
        @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT,
        @folder_name=N'Allusr_ImportsAndExports',
        @project_name=N'Imports',
        @use32bitruntime=TRUE,
        @reference_id=Null
    SELECT @execution_id

    --run synchronously so the rest of the code doesn't run until after it's done.
    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
        @execution_id
        , @object_type = 50                     -- System parameter
        , @parameter_name = N'SYNCHRONIZED'
        , @parameter_value = 1

    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value]
        @execution_id,
        @object_type=30,
        @parameter_name=N'ActionID',
        @parameter_value=@ActionID

    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value]
        @execution_id,
        @object_type=30,
        @parameter_name=N'FileName',
        @parameter_value=@FileName

    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
END
```

[Edit: I should also add that this stored procedure was certificate signed with a certificate user with ReadWrite permissions to the current database.]

I've tested this as two different users. When running as the first one (who I'll call WorkingUser), it works without a hitch (everything gets imported, etc.) When I run as the second user (who I'll call FailingUser) it fails with the application error listed earlier, but no other errors that I can see.

WorkingUser is a SQL Server sysadmin and the creator of the packages. WorkingUser has full permissions to the Excel file's directory.

FailingUser is a member of the SSISDB.public and msdb.db_ssisoperator roles. FailingUser's permissions to the Excel file's directory are the same as WorkingUser's.

SSISDB.public has Read, Execute Objects, and Read Objects permissions to the "Allusr_ImportsAndExports" SSIS package folder, and Read and Execute permissions to the "Imports" folder.

Thanks. :)

[Edit with further info: After I finally remembered that the "All Executions" SSIS report was a thing that exists, I found that it's erroring with a "Select permissions denied on table" error. The package is supposed to insert unmatched records from the spreadsheet into a table that "FailingUser" does not, in fact, have select permissions to. However, the stored procedure running the package is certificate signed, and the user associated with the certificate is a member of db_datareader and db_datawriter for the entire database. I've also replicated the certificate and the user in SSISDB. No change (same error in the reporting).]

Comment: Before I saw your edit it seemed like a permission issue.  I would say to test increase the users permissions (if possible) temporarily to see if that fixes it.  I have seen this sometimes when a person/group has permissions for something and should work because the SP inherits the permissions for all the tables it is selecting from (so if user can execute SP they can do anything on the table in the SP) but some tables I have had (or code in the SP) is more restricted and needs elevated permissions.  Or you can change the SP to run as owner.

Comment: Yep, it's confirmed as a permissions issue. I'm wracking my brain trying to fix it. EXECUTE AS doesn't work because it can't access SSISDB. I've tried certificate signing the procedure and replicating the user in SSISDB, but that's not working. Is there any way to run a procedure that runs an SSIS package, without giving the user full permissions to the table?

Comment: It may be the user does not have permissions to execute the SSIS package itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turned out the answer to the underlying issue was relatively simple. I just had to change the SQL Server connection that was used by the package itself (in VS, then redeployed it after testing). Previously, the SQL Server connection was using Windows Authentication, which meant that the SSIS package had the same (often limited) permissions as the person running the package. I changed it to a SQL-Authenticated user with datareader and datawriter permissions to the database, and that fixed the problem. :)